# how to integrate material icons into opencart

Tags: opencart, google-material-icons

Can anyone explain how to integrate Google material icons into Opencart or into any other website?
Here is the link to [Google material icons](https://material.io/icons).

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a CSS framework like this: http://materializecss.com/icons.html

it is really close to the material design of Google

Comment: Not the same what I need but got an idea from this if anyone wants here is the link for [google material icons inegration](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons). thanks @Andreas

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I assume its more less the same like the icons from google. as written in the docs, they include a google font called "Material Icons". I guess there are more icons as shown on the page